# CHARINDEX always 0 when looking for substring

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have the following in a field ABCD, EFG, HIJ and can confirm this by selecting it.  I need to be able to search this string for ABCD so I used the following:

```
case
when CHARINDEX(g.letters ,'ABCD') <> 0
then (- 2)
else (- 1)
end
```

However its always returning -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
CHARINDEX('ABCD', g.letters)
```

The [first parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) is the expression to find and the second parameter is the expression to be searched.

Comment: That'll teach me to post before properly searching!  It seems a lot of people have this problem, what gives?

Comment: @eddy556 - I can never remember this either!

Comment: I would say intuition would put it the other way around?

Comment: Just checked and in VB6 it *is* the other way round. `InStr("the cat sat on the mat", "cat")`